# Ruby implementation of conversion between Latitude/Longitude and OS National Grid Reference point?

Tags: ruby, geospatial

For converting between Latitude/Longitude and UK's Ordnance Survey National Grid eastings and northings, this seems to be the most popular explanation and reference implementation in JavaScript: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html

The web is littered with other implementations in different languages. Making the conversion via PostGIS queries is another alternative.

...but did anyone implement this maths **in ruby**?

LatLongToOSGrid is the direction I'm looking for just at this moment, but I would have thought a library for converting in both directions must surely be available in a gem somewhere. I'm just not searching for the right thing.

Comment: Here are some libraries in .Net, COM, Proj4... I don't know whether you can call them in Ruby http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867950/is-there-a-free-net-library-to-convert-osgb36-to-wgs84

Comment: And the Ordnance Survey offer a free developer's pack with details of their "OSTN02/OSGM02" transformation and unit tests. Pretty heavy though. http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/gps/osnetfreeservices/furtherinfo/questdeveloper.html

Comment: Richard Fairhurst suggested Proj4 to me too, pointing out it has ruby bindings: http://proj4rb.rubyforge.org/proj4rb-doc/classes/Proj4.html Haven't tried that yet, but it looks like a good solution. Still surprised it hasn't been done in pure ruby though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now ported the javascript code to Ruby.

See [my blog post "Ruby code for converting to UK Ordnance Survey coordinate systems from WGS84?"](http://www.harrywood.co.uk/blog/2010/06/29/ruby-code-for-converting-to-uk-ordnance-survey-coordinate-systems-from-wgs84/)

And the linked code [osgbconvert.rb](http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/osgbconvert.rb)

The blog post also details the proj4 ruby bindings approach and explains the coordinate systems involved.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a gem based on information derived from Harry's blog that I hope will be useful. The gem is call global_convert and the code can be found at https://github.com/reggieb/global_convert